# jQuery UI draggable & position relative, change to absolute on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a problem with jQuery UI. When i set elements resizable, draggable & droppable, like this

```
$("#ml1,#ml2,#ml3,#ml4,#ml5").resizable({ grid: [ 20, 10 ] }).droppable().draggable();
```

,and that i resize one, his position pass to absolute... Why ? When i just set the object resizable & droppable, it's ok, the position style didn't change..

Here is a JSFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NLHYF/

I want that the objects that i resize keep their relative position.

Thank you

Comment: Could you clearly explain whats the problem is?

Comment: You point it out ! It's beacause your bloc is draggable. When you drag an object, it still keep its ancestors in the DOM. The only way to move it in the screen is to change is coordinate by modifiying `top` and `left` values. The only way is to make it absolutely positionned. Fixed will fix the bloc and relative may change the behaviour of its children

Comment: In addition, what I suggest is to nest each items in a invisible div that will positionned like your actual list. The aim is to supress issues with `relative` and `absolute` position. Maybe you will need to make the container div as draggable, so the visible item will be the handler for dragging.

Comment: Ok, i get something better, i will work on it ! http://jsfiddle.net/epN56/

Comment: has to be that way, otherwise I would not be superimposed